# Unknown column in 'field list' (does not involve backticks)

Tags: mysql, sql

Albums: AlbumID, Title, Date_created, Date_modified

Images: ImageID, Title, Credit

Together: AlbumID, ImageID

```
SELECT `Images.ImageID` 
FROM `Images` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Together` 
      ON Images.ImageID=Together.ImageID 
WHERE Together.ImageID IS NULL
```

But when I enter the query it changes it to:

```
SELECT `Images.ImageID` 
FROM `Images` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Together` 
      ON Images.ImageID=Together.ImageID 
WHERE Together.ImageID IS NULL LIMIT 0, 25
```

and gives me the error:
    `#1054 - Unknown column 'Images.ImageID' in 'field list`'

I've looked at other people's questions with the same problem, but the solution for all of theirs seemed to be that they were using single quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: If more people new that you don't need any kind of quotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't escape names that don't need to be escaped.  Also, learn to use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.  So:

```
SELECT i.ImageID 
FROM Images i LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Together t 
     ON i.ImageID = t.ImageID 
WHERE t.ImageID IS NULL;
```

When you write:

```
SELECT `Images.ImageID`
```

The MySQL is looking for a column called, literally, "Images.ImageID".  It is not looking for `ImageId` in `Images`, because you have enclosed them in backticks, which says that they are one identifier.